# HashMap with multiple Value

Tags: java, multimap

I want to implement Hash table with multiple values in java i.e

```
// if sample is a hashmap
sample.put(1,1);
sample.put(1,2);
```

and `sample.get(1);` will return 2 values.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You need to make the "value" a List.

Comment: Make the value a subclass of Collection, such as ArrayList. The code you have above will not accumulate 1 and 2 but rather replace 1 with 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Multimap instead. It keeps multiple values for a key in a list. There are implementations in [commons-collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html) and in [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

```
Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();   
multimap.put("ducks", "Huey");
multimap.put("ducks", "Dewey");
multimap.put("ducks", "Louie");
Collection<String> ducks = multimap.get("ducks");
System.out.println(ducks); // [Huey, Dewey, Louie]
```

It is similar to using a Hashmap where the values are lists, but you don't have to explicitly create the lists.

The same example done the do-it-yourself way looks like:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ducks", new ArrayList<String>());
map.get("ducks").add("Huey");
map.get("ducks").add("Dewey");
map.get("ducks").add("Louie");
// or as an alternative to the prev 4 lines:
// map.put("ducks", new ArrayList<String>(
//     new String[] {"Huey", "Dewey", "Louie"}));
Collection<String> ducks = map.get("ducks");
System.out.println(ducks); // [Huey, Dewey, Louie]
```

Note that you can use the Multimap as a builder and call [asMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#asMap%28%29) on it to return a map.

Comment: @Unihedron: yes, that would work. adding that as an alternative, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try `HashMap<Key, List<Value>>`  You will need to manage the list, creating if it doesn't exist already, and adding to it if you need.

Guava also provides a [Multimap](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) implementation

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way

```
Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>();
List listOne = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
    listOne.add(i);
}
List listTwo = new ArrayList();
for(int i=4;i<6;i++){
    listTwo.add(i);
}
map.put("listOne",listOne);
map.put("listTwo",listTwo);
```

Or you can even use Guava's Multimap